# Using LISTAGG/XMLAGG not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

`LISTAGG` is Working with `< 4000` but not `> 4000`. When I tried giving `XMLAGG` instead of `LISTAGG`, it does not work.

```
SELECT LISTAGG( 
    CONCAT(
        CONCAT( 
            ( 
                SELECT CONCAT( USER_FIRST_NM, CONCAT(',', USER_LAST_NM) )
                FROM USER_TABLE
                WHERE USER_LOGONID = USER_ID
            ), 
            CONCAT( ' - ', TO_CHAR(CREATED_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY HH:MI AM'))
        ),
        CONCAT(chr(10), NOTES) 
    ),
    chr(10)
) WITHIN GROUP (
    ORDER BY 
    MOBILES,
    created_date ASC
) NOTES
FROM MOBILES_notes
WHERE MOBILES_ELEMENT = :p1
ORDER BY CREATED_DATE
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What exactly is your question? Consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help focus your post on the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XMLAGG()` along with `XMLELEMENT()` function might be used for huge data such as

```
SELECT RTRIM(DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(
       XMLAGG(
                XMLELEMENT(e, 
                CONCAT(CONCAT((SELECT CONCAT(user_first_nm,
                                           CONCAT(',', user_last_nm))
                               FROM USER_TABLE
                              WHERE user_logonid = user_id),
                             CONCAT(' - ',
                                    TO_CHAR(created_date,
                                            'DD-MON-YY HH:MI AM'))),
                      CONCAT(CHR(10), NOTES))||CHR(10)                
                ) ORDER BY mobiles, created_date
               ).EXTRACT('//text()').GETCLOBVAL() ,1),',') AS notes
  FROM mobiles_notes
 WHERE mobiles_element = :p1
 ORDER BY created_date
```

Comment: WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY MOBILES, created_date ASC) NOTES  --->this condition is missing in the query u mentioned if i keep this in the query iam getting error

Comment: Hi @nandini , I've added the option with order by.